# Выдача роли discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

Здраствуйте , прошу помощи, делаю команду что бы можно было открывать коробки , как приз хотела добавить роль но к сожалению перебрала кучу способов что бы бот выдавал роль.
Заранее благодарю за вашу помощь

Что показывает консоль:

```
452880569181667328
Бот в сети!
Ignoring exception in command __gifts:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Alina\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Alina\Desktop\залить\bot.py", line 240, in __gifts
    await ctx.author.add_roles(role22)
  File "C:\Users\Alina\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\discord\member.py", line 676, in add_roles
    await req(guild_id, user_id, role.id, reason=reason)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Alina\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 902, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\Alina\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 864, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Alina\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'
```

Кусочек кода

```
@client.command(aliases = ['открыть'])
@commands.cooldown(1, 1, commands.BucketType.user)
async def __gifts(ctx, member: discord.Member=None, role: discord.Role = None, amount = 0):
    randomgif = random.randint(1, 3)
    rmBal = random.randint(690, 4900)
    rmCol = random.randint(2, 25)

    role22 = ctx.guild.get_role(738095317181923349)  



    if cursor.execute("SELECT gift FROM users WHERE id = {}".format(ctx.author.id)).fetchone()[0] == int(amount):
        await ctx.send('У вас нет коробок')
        return

    if randomgif == 1:
        emb = discord.Embed(title =f'{ctx.author.name} твоя коробка открыта <a:785745724893429780:800469168741679155>', color=0x9b00ff)
        #, description=f'Вы получили: **{rmBon}**<a:y_star:791077278309285908> \nНайдено краски: **{rdColl}**<a:roza:810772974851850240> \nТаинственных лайков: **{rdLike}**', 
        emb.add_field(name='Вот что в ней находилось:', value=f'Деньги на баланс в виде: **{rmBal}**<a:y_star:791077278309285908>\nКраска: **{rmCol}**<a:roza:810772974851850240>\nНайдена роль: <@&779978073457688576>')
        emb.set_thumbnail(url=ctx.author.avatar_url)

        cursor.execute("UPDATE users SET cash = cash + {} WHERE id = {}".format(rmBal, ctx.author.id))  
        cursor.execute('UPDATE users SET colors = colors + {} WHERE id = {}'.format(rmCol, ctx.author.id))
        cursor.execute("UPDATE users SET gift = gift - {} WHERE id = {}".format(1, ctx.author.id))
        connection.commit()
        role22 = ctx.guild.get_role(738095317181923349) 
        await ctx.author.add_roles(role22)
        await ctx.send(embed = emb)

    if randomgif == 2:
        emb = discord.Embed(title =f'{ctx.author.name} твоя коробка открыта 2 <a:785745724893429780:800469168741679155>', color=0x9b00ff)
        #, description=f'Вы получили: **{rmBon}**<a:y_star:791077278309285908> \nНайдено краски: **{rdColl}**<a:roza:810772974851850240> \nТаинственных лайков: **{rdLike}**', 
        emb.add_field(name='Вот что в ней находилось:', value=f'Деньги на баланс в виде: **{rmBal}**<a:y_star:791077278309285908>\nКраска: **{rmCol}**<a:roza:810772974851850240>')
        emb.set_thumbnail(url=ctx.author.avatar_url)


        cursor.execute("UPDATE users SET cash = cash + {} WHERE id = {}".format(rmBal, ctx.author.id))  
        cursor.execute('UPDATE users SET colors = colors + {} WHERE id = {}'.format(rmCol, ctx.author.id))
        cursor.execute("UPDATE users SET gift = gift - {} WHERE id = {}".format(1, ctx.author.id))
        connection.commit()

        await ctx.send(embed = emb)
```

Comment: Судя по трассе ошибки в `role22` будет `None`

Comment: Да.. Я заметила .. И читала это где то про такую же ситуацию, но решение из того случая мне не помог .

Answer (score 2):

Ошибка из-за того, что вы передали `None` в `add_roles`:

```
role22 = ctx.guild.get_role(738095317181923349)
await ctx.author.add_roles(role22)
```

Метод [ctx.guild.get_role](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.get_role) вернет `None`, если указанная роль не найдена, поэтому проверяйте ее результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]